# What are the screws for on the UltraSPARC?

Tags: cpu

[image]

I fail to grasp what can be screwed on them, can you explain what are these for?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They are used for attaching a heat sink.

[image: Sun UltraSPARC with heatsink]

Comment: Beat me to it.  Here's a [link to an ebay listing](https://www.ebay.com/p/1826083805) showing an UltraSPARC CPU module with the heatsink in place.

Comment: I was trying to think where else I'd seen that sort of thing - the DEC Alpha 21064 package has screws too.

Comment: And who can forget the [torque screwdriver that came inside the Sun 280r (p71 of the PDF)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/280r.srvr/806-4807-10/806-4807-10.pdf)  :-D  Sun Type 7 keyboards are still the best....

Comment: The heatskink is bolted to the daughterboard too (rhs of your photo) I don't recall if there's a clamp holding the CPU's pins too, or if the big sandwich is doing all the retention of CPU as well.